# Dual boot Endeavor OS changed to EFI hard drive after BIOS update

Tags: bios, uefi, arch-linux, dualboot

I dual booted windows 11 and Endeavor OS on my HP notebook without any problem, but after a BIOS update the Boot options menu listed Endeavour os as EFI hard drive.

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkKu.jpg)

Also now the OS boot manager doesn't show Endeavour OS as another OS and thus cannot choose the os on bootup.

[Image showing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR3VW.jpg)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update: I reinstalled Grub and now I can see grub in the OS boot manager, but when I tried to change the order it wouldn't let me, and also when I tried changing the order from EasyUEFI it would always reset after rebooting, How can I fix this?

[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVFkB.jpg)

Comment: Reinstall Grub. The dirty&lazy possible solution is using EasyUEFI in Windows. It may or may not detect the other OS.

Comment: I installed EasyUEFI and changed the boot order by setting Endeavor os first and windows second but after rebooting, the order gets reset, how do I fix this?

Comment: Again, reinstall Grub.

Comment: Reinstalled Grub, Grub has appeared in the boot order, now what should I do?

Comment: If properly reinstalled it should now show up in UEFI > Boot menu.

Comment: Yes grub is there now, but I am not able to change the order, windows boot manager is still no 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by first re-installing grub in root and then later changing the OS boot manager order in the BIOS, which solved my problem, The thing I didn't know was that you had to press F10 after changing the OS boot manager order or else it wouldn't get saved.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).